# Couchbase Test Running Failed

Tags: caching, memcached, couchbase

I installed Couchbase and trying to test its caching. The URL `localhost:8091/index.html` shows all most everything (stats,server info etc). When I tel net `telnet localhost 8091`  terminal shows
`Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.`

Then I tried to get the status with command `stats`  . Also, I tried to set a key-value . Both commands give the same error:
`HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 Server: MochiWeb/1.0 (Any of you quaids got a smint?)
 Date: Fri, 01 Aug 2014 05:28:31 GMT
 Content-Length: 0`

1. Does this sound my installation has any issue or couchbase not running well?
2. Does couchbase heavily depend on hardware specifications ? (it asks for more core servers, more MEMORY).
   How ever,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to telnet into the HTTP admin (UI) port 8091. To issue test commands in ASCII (e.g. `stats`) use port 11211 (to connect to the legacy ASCII memcached proxy, moxi).

Comment: Thank you very much Dave. he 11211 port is memcached port.Isn't it?. If we use 11211 port, then all stats of memcached are shown. I already installed memcached and it is running. What happens to the already installed memcached instance when I've installed the couchbase ?

Comment: So by default Couchbase also installs a memcache proxy (moxi) which listens on the legacy memcache port (`12111`), converts to the Couchbase smart SDK protocol and passes the commands to Couchbase (port `11210`). I'm not sure what happens to moxi if the `11211` is in use - I assume it does nothing. I suggest if you want to test then you use a smart client to validate the Couchbase server - see http://www.couchbase.com/communities/

Comment: Unless you have a very specific use case that you require Moxi, you should use the Client SDKs for normal data interaction with Couchbase. Moxi is only there for legacy backwards compatibility with memcached and does not have nearly the capabilities that the SDKs do. Even if you were to use Moxi for a legacy use case, you would be wise to transition your application to using the client SDKs sooner rather than later.